# Do I get the meaning of the sentence correctly?

Tags: meaning, sentence

This text is about keeping your inbox as empty as possible. The second sentence confused me. I guess the author says that achieving the simplicity of "One touch" method requires a lot of efforts and most people do not understand that. Do I get the meaning of the sentence correctly??

The key to Inbox Zero, everyone knows, is to “touch each email only once.” 
But what most do not appreciate is that this level of simplicity is the ultimate sophistication — only a well-designed underlying system can make such elegant action possible.

https://medium.com/forte-labs/one-touch-to-inbox-zero-a74cfa02e5bf#.7xz9zqewh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, the meaning of the second sentence is to point out that the trivialized goal of only touching emails once is actually the culmination of a lot of hard work and thought put into a system that makes it possible.